# Setting href using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set a message using below Jquery  statement..The "Here" in the message should be linked to href link..

How can do that using the same Jquery stmt?

```
$('#message').html('Access Denied: .Click Here to login with your card.')
```

Comment: You mean like `$('#message').html('Access Denied: .Click <a href="page.html">Here</a> to login with your card.')`?

Comment: Well then I guess that's settled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#message').html('Access Denied: .Click <a href="mylink.html">Here</a> to login with your card.')`

jQuery will parse the html within the string when inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#test").click(function(){
var link = "<a href='www.google.cl'>Here</a>"    
$('#message').html('Access Denied: .Click '+link+' to login with your card.')
});
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/bG38U/